# Understanding transactions and WATCH

Tags: redis

I am reading https://redis.io/docs/manual/transactions/, and I am not sure I fully understand the importance of `WATCH` in a Redis transaction. From https://redis.io/docs/manual/transactions/#usage, I am led to believe `EXEC` is atomic:

```
> MULTI
OK
> INCR foo
QUEUED
> INCR bar
QUEUED
> EXEC
1) (integer) 1
2) (integer) 1
```

But between `MULTI` and `EXEC`, the values at keys `foo` and `bar` could have been changed (e.g. in response to a request from another client). Is that why `WATCH` is useful? To error out the transaction if e.g. `foo` or `bar` changed after `MULTI` and before `EXEC`?

Do I have it correct? Anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

> I am led to believe EXEC is atomic

YES

> Is that why WATCH is useful? To error out the transaction if e.g. foo or bar changed after MULTI and before EXEC?

NOT exactly. Redis fails the transaction if some key the client **WATCH**ed before the transaction has been changed (after WATCH and before EXEC). The watched key might even not used in transaction.

MULTI-EXEC ensures commands between them runs atomically, while WATCH provides check-and-set(CAS) behavior.

With MULTI-EXEC, Redis ensures running `INCR foo` and `INCR bar` atomically, otherwise, Redis might run some other commands between `INCR foo` and `INCR bar` (these commands might and might not change *foo* or *bar*). If you watch some key (either *foo*, or *bar*, or even any other keys) before the transaction, and the watched key has been modified since the WATCH command, the transaction fails.

### UPDATE

The doc you referred has a good example of using WATCH: implement `INCR` with `GET` and `SET`. In order to implement `INCR`, you need to 1) `GET` the old counter from Redis, 2) incr it on client side, and 3) `SET` the new value to Redis. In order to make it work, you need to ensure no other clients update/change the counter after you run step 1, otherwise, you might write incorrect value and should fail the transaction. 2 clients both get the old counter, i.e. 1, and incr it locally, and client 1 update it to 2, then client 2 update it to 2 again (the counter should be 3). In this case, WATCH is helpful.

```
WATCH mykey
val = GET mykey
val = val + 1
MULTI
SET mykey $val
EXEC
```

If some other client update the counter after we watch it, the transaction fails.

> When do watched keys no longer watched?

1. EXEC is called.
2. UNWATCH is called.
3. DISCARD is called.
4. connection is closed.

Comment: To be extra clear, the commands between MULTI and EXEC run when EXEC is called. Until that point, they are queued up.

Comment: So if EXEC is already atomic, then what would be a simple example of a situation where WATCH is necessary? Also, are the WATCH keys no longer watched after the first subsequent EXEC is called?